# Solve for $x$ an inequality with logarithms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am trying to solve this equation

$\frac{(n(n-1))}{2}  + X (2\log n +2) < nX  $

I would like to solve it for X ?
What should i do  ?
Thanks

Comment: Type it into Wolfram Alpha...

Comment: It's not an equation, much less a system of equations, and has nothing to do with complex analysis, so I'm retagging (and maybe retitling).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

The inequality being $$X (2 \log (n)+2)+\frac{(n-1) n}{2}  < n X$$ substract $nX$ for both side and $\frac{(n-1) n}{2} $ from both sides too. You then arrive to $$X (2 \log (n)+2-n) < -\frac{(n-1) n}{2} $$ which looks like $a X< b$ Now, the problem is with the signs of $a=(2 \log (n)+2-n)$ and $b=-\frac{(n-1) n}{2} $. Assuming that $n$ is an integer,$b$ is always negative or zero. But, for $a$, the problem is quite different.

If you look at the function $$f(n)=2 \log (n)+2-n$$ its derivative is $f'(n)=\frac{2}{n}-1$ which cancels for $n=2$ and $f(2)=2\log(2)$ which is positive. The second derivative test shows that this corresponds to a maximum. So, taking into account the behavior of the different pieces, there are two values $n_1$ and $n_2$ of $n$ which makes $f(n)=0$. You could easily check that $f(n)$ is positive only if $1<n<6$.

I am sure that you can take from here.